# FindMinimum function does not produce minimum from near point

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Using my simple program and I would like to find such matrix elements that minimize difference of their eigenvalues.

```
H1 = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};  
H2 = {{2, 2}, {3, 2}};  
f1[R_, S_] := R*H1 + S*IdentityMatrix[2]  
f2[R_, S_] := S*H2 + R*IdentityMatrix[2]  
Evl1 = N[Eigenvalues[f1[R, S]]];  
Evl2 = N[Eigenvalues[f2[R, S]]];  
h[R_, S_] := Evl1[[1]] - Evl2[[1]]  
h[1, 1]  
FindMinimum[h[R, S], {R, 1}, {S, 1}]
```

Problems encountered are as follows:
1. Inserting values {1,1} into defined function h does not produce any specific numerical value, but an expression depending on variables R,S.
2. FindMinimum function does not produce minimum from near point. When trying to find minimum point, I found close solution {0.87, 1.101}.
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You probably want the `Evl1` and `Evl2` lines to used deferred evaluation, _i.e._ `:=`.

Answer (score 4):

You have a couple problems.  First, as Andrew Cheong pointed out, `Evl1` and `Evl2` should be `SetDelayed` (`:=`).  As you can see from evaluating `h[1,1]`, `S` and `R` don't seem to get substituted:

```
h[1, 1]
(* -R + 0.44949 S + 0.5 (-0.744563 R + 2. S) *)
```

This is because Mathematica first `Sets` (`=`) the values of the `Evl*` to expressions involving the *symbols* `R` and `S`.  However, the definition of `h` involves the *named patterns* `R_` and `S_`.  `R` and `S` in the right-hand-side don't ever get replaced, since they're "hidden" by the `Evl*`.  You probably want something like this:

```
Evl1[R_, S_] := N[Eigenvalues[f1[R, S]]]
Evl2[R_, S_] := N[Eigenvalues[f2[R, S]]]
h[R_, S_] := Evl1[R, S][[1]] - Evl2[R, S][[1]]
```

Now the `Evl*` take in `R` and `S` and compute the correct value:

```
h[1, 1]
(* 0.922792 *)
```

And now `FindMinimum` returns a value:

```
FindMinimum[h[R, S], {{R, 1}, {S, 1}}]
(* {-2.09628*10^17, {R -> 7.22028*10^16, S -> -7.62651*10^16}} *)
```

We also get a warning message:

```
FindMinimum::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within the tolerance
specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient
decrease in the function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working
precision to meet these tolerances. >>
```

We can get an idea of why this happens by plotting `h`:

```
Plot3D[h[R, S], {R, -5, 5}, {S, -5, 5}, MaxRecursion -> 5, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}]
```

[image]

The plot of `h` just keeps sloping downward as `R` gets bigger and `S`
 gets smaller.  This is because `FindMinimum` will try to make `h` as *negative* as possible, which means it will end up making the difference as large as possible.  You can fix that by minimizing the absolute difference (with `Abs`) or the square of the distance (which behaves better numerically):

```
h[R_, S_] := (Evl1[R, S][[1]] - Evl2[R, S][[1]])^2
Plot3D[h[R, S], {R, -2, 2}, {S, -2, 2}, MaxRecursion -> 4, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}]
```

[image]

We can see now that there is a clear minimum value, and so `FindMinimum` works as expected.

```
h[1, 1] (* 0.851544 *)
FindMinimum[h[R, S], {{R, 1}, {S, 1}}]
(* {1.2326*10^-32, {R -> 1.02659, S -> 0.971911}} *)
```

---

There is one more issue.  `R` and `S` are not independent of each other.  Imagine multiplying both of them by two: then the `f*` will both be exactly doubled, and their eigenvalues `Evl*` will also be exactly doubled.  If their difference was zero before, it will be zero again.  You can see this in the plot of `h`, where the minimum is a long trough with `h` on the centerline equal to zero.

You probably want to fix a condition like `R + S == 1`.  You can do this by redefining the `f*`, `Evl*`, and `h` to be functions of only `S`, replacing `R` by `1-S`; or, you can use a condition in `FindMinimum:`

```
FindMinimum[{h[R, S], R + S == 1}, {{R, 1}, {S, 1}}]
(* {1.2326*10^-32, {R -> 0.513681, S -> 0.486319}} *)
```

Plotting shows that with this condition, there is a single minima:

```
Plot[h[s, 1 - s], {s, -2, +2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome answer.

Comment: @AndrewCheong Hope you don't mind that I took part of the solution from your comment...

Comment: Oh of course not. I only pointed out the most obvious piece, and didn't bother to actually help. You're too considerate :-) Anyone would have seen that even without my comment.